# Extract nth occurrence of a number from a string

Tags: google-sheets

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11t5pG_XQ-eCrhS19FBjXid7Mp4uNql-tdz8ubtdnMrw/edit?usp=sharing)

I have an =IMPORTHTML function in my spreadsheet that imports a table on a website containing information I need for my spreadsheet.  One of these imported cells contains a text string with three different numbers in it.  I only need the third number.  How can I extract this third number?

I've tried using the following formula, but it only gives me the first occurrence of a number:

```
=regexextract(A1,"[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **String in A2:**

> Represents a 90% confidence range based on a sample of 280 runs.
> 100 runs are done at a time.
> Add data to the log (requires JavaScript).

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d+) runs ")
```

If the test string is of the exact format as shown above, the above `REGEX` should work.

- `\d+` represents one or more digits.
- `()` inside REGEX represent capture group.

## **EDIT:**

Based on the clarification that test strings can also be "run" instead of "runs",

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d+) run(?:s){0,1} ")
```

Or

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?m)^(\d+)")
```

should work.

Ref: https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, for some reason, it doesn't work if the number is more than one digit long.  It takes the right-most number.  So "10" becomes "0" for example.

Comment: The first formula would work perfectly except that the string changes if the third number is "1".  Instead of saying "runs" it says "run".

Comment: Completely perfect.  I'm sorry about the late clarification.  It wasn't until I tested your first function that I discovered "runs" changes to "run" if the number was "1".  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Since the text string is always identical with the exception of the three numbers in it, it appears I've managed to do what I want with this:

```
=RIGHT(index(split(A2, " "),12), LEN(index(split(A2, " "),12))-6)
```

It's not as clean as what I was hoping for, but it seems to work.